# Difference between Math.IEEEremainder() and StrictMath.IEEEremainder()

Tags: java, math

I found `IEEEremainder()` at two places in `lang` package.

1. `java.lang.Math.IEEEremainder()`
2. `java.lang.StrictMath.IEEEremainder()`

My question is both methods are same or they are different?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As spelled out in the documentation:

> Unlike some of the numeric methods of class `StrictMath`, all implementations of the equivalent functions of class `Math` are not defined to return the bit-for-bit same results. This relaxation permits better-performing implementations where strict reproducibility is not required.

Since the x86(-64) architecture uses IEEE 754 floating-point, on the x86 OpenJDK implementation, `Math` tends to delegate to `StrictMath`, and does so in this case, but that is not required by the specification.

Answer (score 2):

At least in OpenJDK, the `Math` version delegates to the `StrictMath` according to [grepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/lang/Math.java#Math.IEEEremainder%28double%2Cdouble%29):

```
public static double IEEEremainder(double f1, double f2) {
    return StrictMath.IEEEremainder(f1, f2); // delegate to StrictMath
}
```